# store loop values in list and reuse list

Tags: r, list, loops, for-loop

I have loop values storing into a list when I run the code below, but when I call the list again, 19 null values display.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```r
my_list <- list()
my_list

nums <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20) #create number list
print(nums)

for(i in nums){
  output <-cat(paste(i^2,""))
  my_list[i] <- output
}

my_list
```

Values appear as follows after running the last two lines:  1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81 100 121 144 169 196 225 256 289 324 361 400

When I run my_list again, I get the following but want the values that were shown to appear.

```
[[1]] 
Null

[[2]]
Null
.
.
.
[[19]]
Null
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Don't use [`cat()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cat.html); [`paste()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/paste.html) is sufficient for your goal.
2. Refer to [list elements with double brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1169456/1082435) (*ie*, `my_list[[i]]` instead of `my_list[i]`).

```r
my_list <- list()

nums <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20) #create number list

for(i in nums){
  output       <- paste(i^2,"")
  my_list[[i]] <- output
}
my_list
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
[1] "1 "

[[2]]
[1] "4 "

...

[[20]]
[1] "400 "
```